# Flutter - Disable a button, not all buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am getting a list from Firebase. The list loads as expected, However I have two issues.

1 - When the button in one item from the list is disabled, all the buttons in the other items also get disabled. I don't want this to happen. How can I get passed this?

2 - I am getting "positiveCount" and "negativeCount" from firebase RTDB. I want to get total (positiveCount + negativeCount) and then calculate the percentage of "positiveCount". (Example: positiveCount = 2, negativeCount = 2, percentage of positiveCount should be 50 percent). The problem is, ıf there is only one item that is loaded, it works perfectly. If there is more than one item loaded, I get an error.

Exception:

```
Exception has occurred.
UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt)
```

My Code:

```
import 'package:colour/colour.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class VaccineCenterList extends StatefulWidget {
  const VaccineCenterList({key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String idScreen = "VaccineCenterList";

  @override
  _VaccineCenterListState createState() => _VaccineCenterListState();
}

class _VaccineCenterListState extends State<VaccineCenterList> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  List<Hospitals> driverList = [];

  late String isTrueOrFalse = "False";

  // // double percentageInt = 0.0;
  int totalVotes = 0;
  // int percentage = 0;

  int positiveCount = 0;
  int negativeCount = 0;

  bool buttonPressed = true;

  TextEditingController hospitalCountyEditingController =
      TextEditingController();

  Future<List<Hospitals>> getHospitalDetails() async {
    try {
      if ((hospitalCountyEditingController.text != "") &&
          (hospitalCountyEditingController.text != " ")) {
        databaseReference
            .child("Hospitals")
            .child(hospitalCountyEditingController.text)
            .onValue
            .listen(
          (event) {
            setState(
              () {
                var value = event.snapshot.value;
                driverList = Map.from(value)
                    .values
                    .map((e) => Hospitals.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                    .toList();
              },
            );
          },
        );
      } else {}
    } catch (e) {
      
    }
    return driverList;
  }

  calculatePositivePercentage(
      positiveCount, negativeCount) {
    // this method gets the number of "yes" and "no" votes. Then calculates the
    // percentage of people who voted "yes".

    // total = positiveCount + negativeCount;
    // percentage = (positiveCount * 100) ~/ total;

    totalVotes = positiveCount + negativeCount;
    int percentage = positiveCount * 100;
    double votePercentage = percentage / totalVotes;

    
    return votePercentage;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("I'm in the vaccine list search screen");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Pamoja",
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 35,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: hospitalCountyEditingController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Search County",
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                    hintStyle: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  buttonPressed = false;
                  setState(() {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                      FocusNode(),
                    );
                    driverList.clear();
                    if (hospitalCountyEditingController.text == "" ||
                        hospitalCountyEditingController.text == " ") {
                      isTrueOrFalse = "False";
                    } else {
                      isTrueOrFalse = "True";
                    }
                  });
                  getHospitalDetails();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Search",
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                // color: Colors.black,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: driverList.isEmpty
                      ? Center(
                          // child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          child: (isTrueOrFalse == "True")
                              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                          "Search for one of the counties below",
                                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega()),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Nairobi, Baringo, Busia, Bomet, Bungoma, Elgeyo Marakwet, Embu, Garissa, Homa Bay, Isiolo, Kajiado, Kakamega, Kericho, Kiambu, Kilifi, Kirinyaga, Kisii, Kisumu, Kitui, Kwale, Laikipia, Lamu, Machakos, Makueni, Mandera, Marsabit, Meru, Migori, Mombasa, Muranga, Nakuru, Nandi, Narok, Nyamira, Nyandarua, Nyeri, Samburu, Siaya County, Taita Taveta, Tana River County, Tharaka Nithi, Trans Nzoia, Turkana, Uasin Gishu, Vihiga, Wajir, West Pokot",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                        )
                      : ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: driverList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                            final Hospitals hospitals = driverList[index];
                            final String hospitalLocaiton = hospitals.location;
                            final String hospitalPhone = hospitals.phone;
                            // final int totalVotes = hospitals.totalVotes;
                            final String hospitalName = hospitals.name;
                            // final String county = hospitals.county;

                            positiveCount = hospitals.positiveCount;
                            negativeCount = hospitals.negativeCount;

                            // final int percentage = positiveCount * 100;
                            // final double percentageInt =
                            //     percentage / totalVotes;

                            // ignore: unused_local_variable
                            final double setpercentage =
                                calculatePositivePercentage(positiveCount, negativeCount);
                            **final percentageInt = setpercentage.toInt();**

                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 0,
                                child: ExpansionTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    hospitalName.toUpperCase(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          child: (hospitalPhone.isNotEmpty)
                                              ? ElevatedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    Clipboard.setData(
                                                      ClipboardData(
                                                        text: hospitalPhone,
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                            Colors.green,
                                                        content: Text(
                                                          "Number Copied",
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    hospitalPhone,
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style:
                                                        GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                            fontSize: 13),
                                                  ),
                                                  style:
                                                      ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                    elevation: 0,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : const Text(""),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 5,
                                        ),
                                        hospitalLocaiton.isNotEmpty
                                            ? Container(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                ),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  hospitalLocaiton,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                    fontSize: 12,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            : Text(
                                                hospitalLocaiton,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "$percentageInt% (percent) of voters say this hospital administer vaccines.",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        const Divider(
                                          // thickness: 1,
                                          indent: 20,
                                          endIndent: 20,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "Does this Hospital administer Vaccines?\n(To help the public, please vote only if you know.)",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        // Container(
                                        //   child: (positiveCount == 0)
                                        //       ? Text("Votes: $positiveCount")
                                        //       : Text("Votes: " +
                                        //           positiveCount.toString()),
                                        // ),
                                        Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                              children: [
                                                ElevatedButton(
                                                  onLongPress: buttonPressed
                                                      ? () {
                                                          buttonPressed = false;
                                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                                  context)
                                                              .showSnackBar(
                                                            const SnackBar(
                                                              backgroundColor:
                                                                  Colors
                                                                      .purpleAccent,
                                                              content: Text(
                                                                "Vote Removed",
                                                                textAlign:
                                                                    TextAlign
                                                                        .center,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                          undoPositiveIncrement(
                                                              hospitalName);
                                                        }
                                                      : null,
                                                  onPressed: buttonPressed ? () {
                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                            Colors.greenAccent,
                                                        content: Text(
                                                          "Voted Yes",
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                    positiveIncrement(
                                                        hospitalName);
                                                  } : null,
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "Yes - $positiveCount",
                                                    style: GoogleFonts
                                                        .lexendMega(),
                                                  ),
                                                  style:
                                                      ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                    primary: Colour("#87D68D"),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                ElevatedButton(
                                                  onLongPress: buttonPressed ? () {
                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                            Colors.purpleAccent,
                                                        content: Text(
                                                          "Vote Removed",
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                    undoNegativeIncrement(
                                                        hospitalName);
                                                  } : null,
                                                  onPressed: buttonPressed ? () {
                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                            Colors.redAccent,
                                                        content: Text(
                                                          "Voted",
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                    negativeIncrement(
                                                        hospitalName);
                                                  } : null,
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "No - $negativeCount",
                                                    style: GoogleFonts
                                                        .lexendMega(),
                                                  ),
                                                  style:
                                                      ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                    primary: Colour("#E3655B"),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              height: 10,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "Total No. of Votes: ",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                  fontSize: 12),
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              height: 10,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "1 - To vote, tap once\n2 - To Undo vote, tap and hold",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              height: 10,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Hospitals {
  final String name;
  final String phone;
  final String location;
  // final String county;
  final int positiveCount;
  final int negativeCount;
  // final int intPercentage;
  // final int totalVotes;

  Hospitals({
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.location,
    // required this.county,
    required this.positiveCount,
    required this.negativeCount,
    // required this.intPercentage,
    // required this.totalVotes,
  });

  static Hospitals fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Hospitals(
      name: json['HospitalName'],
      phone: json['HospitalPhone'],
      // county: json['county'],
      location: json['HospitalAddres'],
      positiveCount: json['poitiveCount'],
      negativeCount: json['negativeCount'],
      // intPercentage: json['intPercentage'],
      // totalVotes: json['totalVotes']
    );
  }
}
```

**Solution for issue 2:**

```
calculatePositivePercentage(positiveCount, negativeCount) {
    // this method gets the number of "yes" and "no" votes. Then calculates the
    // percentage of people who voted "yes".

    double votePercentage = 0;

    if (positiveCount == 0 && negativeCount == 0) {
      try {
        return votePercentage.toInt();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        totalVotes = positiveCount + negativeCount;
        int percentage = positiveCount * 100;
        votePercentage = percentage / totalVotes;
        return votePercentage.toInt();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: can you highlight which line causes the error? thanks

Comment: @HelsDying sorry I could'nt find where to highlight it.    " final percentageInt = setpercentage.toInt();    "

Comment: Issue 2, solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent all buttons to be disabled instead of

```
bool buttonPressed = true;
```

use

```
List<bool> buttonPressed = [true];
```

and your 2nd error is because may be you are not getting an int value from the response try

```
int.parse();
```

to parse a `String` to `int`

Comment: Solved Issue 2, Could you please explain to me how I can implement your solution for issue 1?

Comment: If you know the number of buttons then just simply add same number of [true,false] in the List of bool then pass them accordingly like buttonPressed[0] and also change the value of the same index

Comment: Thank you, this was actually quite easy to implement.

Comment: Pleased to help you please upvote answer as well. Thanks :)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but I need 15+ reputation for it to reflect.

Comment: @waldokhalid okay thanks